# alias for external links in ( vuejs or vuepress )

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vuepress, vuepress2

**Question:**

What is the proper way to define an alias for external links in vuepress2 or vuejs?

Problem:

I have a documentation site hosted in github pages, I want to link some source files to documentation.

```markdown
[task-runner.json](https://github.com/alirezanet/Husky.Net/blob/master/.husky/task-runner.json)
```

this works but I rather create an alias for the base path. something like this:

```markdown
@repo : 
https://github.com/alirezanet/Husky.Net/blob/master/.husky/task-runner.json
```

and use it like this

```markdown
[task-runner.json](@repo/.husky/task-runner.json)
```

Notes:

- because vuepress2 is using vuejs3, probably vuejs solution works too
- vuepress default-theme also has `repo` configuration, is there any way to use it in router-links or md-files?

```js
import type { DefaultThemeOptions } from 'vuepress'

export const themeConfig: DefaultThemeOptions = {
   docsRepo: 'alirezanet/husky.net',
   repo: 'alirezanet/husky.net',
}
```